# Quiero leer una variable en una posición de memoria de un fichero .elf

Tags: linux, bash, lenguaje-compilado, read

quería leer una variable de un archivo .elf. Por ejemplo, supongamos que tenemos `archivo.elf` y hago

```
readelf -s archivo.elf
```

Hay una variable en 0000000000004040 y quiero leer su contenido. ¿Como puedo leerlo?

Edit1:
Tengo un archivo llamado archivo.elf,que no se lo que tiene. Lo que quiero hacer es volcar el contenido en un fichero para ver mensaje secreto que tiene guardado en la posición de memoria 0000000000004040. No puedo usar códigos externos y solo puedo usar comandos de la terminal de linux.

Comment: eferion- esto lo necesito para un trabajo, no pido el resultado simplemente el como se hace. El profesor nos obliga ha hacerlo desde la propia consola de linux y NO podemos usar nuestros propios scripts para eso. Estoy dándole vueltas al objdump,readelf y objcopy pero no llego a nada.

Comment: Ya, es que solo podemos usar comandos de la consola propia de linux. Fopen se que es para abrir archivos en C pero no puedo hacer mi propio código para abrirlo y mirarlo.

Comment: Lo puse porque el .elf viene de un programa programado en C. Por eso puse C.

Comment: Ya lo modifique.

Comment: por favor añade un ejemplo bastante representativo de cómo es el archivo y cómo quieres tratarlo. ¿Quieres guardar dentro de una variable?

Comment: Ya lo modifique-fedorqui

Comment: Llevo un día tratando de ver como se resuelve eto. Pero mientras no lo encuentro, trata de usar o buscar algo referente a `objdump`, o `ltrace` y `strace`.

Comment: Eso lo he intentado y nada. El post esta puesto por desesperación ya que no encuentro la manera de hacerlo.

Answer (score -1):

`readelf` es un programa que viene por defecto en algunos SO, com en Ubuntu 20, y que lee ficheros `ELF` y nos da información de las tablas de simbolos en memoria, al estilo :

```
ymbol table '.symtab' contains 69 entries:
   Nom.:   Valor          Mida Tipus   Unió   Vis      Nom Ndx
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000000318     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     2: 0000000000000338     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 
     3: 0000000000000358     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 
     4: 000000000000037c     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 
     5: 00000000000003a0     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5 
     6: 00000000000003c8     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6 
     7: 00000000000004d0     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    7 
     8: 0000000000000596     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    8 
     9: 00000000000005b0     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    9 
    10: 00000000000005f0     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   10 
    11: 00000000000006b0     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   11 
    12: 0000000000001000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   12 
    13: 0000000000001020     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 
    14: 0000000000001080     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 
    15: 0000000000001090     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   15 
    16: 00000000000010e0     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 
    17: 00000000000013b8     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   17 
    18: 0000000000002000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   18 
    19: 000000000000203c     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   19 
    20: 0000000000002080     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   20 
    21: 0000000000003d98     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   21 
    22: 0000000000003da0     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   22 
    23: 0000000000003da8     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   23 
    24: 0000000000003f98     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   24 
    25: 0000000000004000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   25 
    26: 0000000000004010     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   26 
    27: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   27 
    28: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS crtstuff.c
    29: 0000000000001110     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 deregister_tm_clones
    30: 0000000000001140     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 register_tm_clones
    31: 0000000000001180     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 __do_global_dtors_aux
    32: 0000000000004010     1 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   26 completed.8060
    33: 0000000000003da0     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   22 __do_global_dtors_aux_fin
    34: 00000000000011c0     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 frame_dummy
    35: 0000000000003d98     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   21 __frame_dummy_init_array_
    36: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS main.c
    37: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS crtstuff.c
    38: 0000000000002184     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   20 __FRAME_END__
```